# Aligning a optimization equation

Tags: multline

I was trying to write a optimization formula which has two part as objective and 2 constraints. But, the objective function is a little bigger and i want to see it in multiline not in single line. But it's not working the way i want it to work. Can someone provide me some good suggestion about how to make it in multiline while the objective function is one equation and constraints are assigned as separate equation. The LaTeX code is like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\label{green}
\text{minimize } & \quad {\sum\nolimits_{\tau=t}^{t+T-1}}s(\tau)[V(\t)-x(\tau)-y(\tau)-Y(\tau)] +{\sum\nolimits_{\tau=t}^{t+T-1}}[(X(\tau)+Y(\tau))(b(\tau)-v(\tau))] \\
\text{subject to } & \quad \quad {something1}\\
& \quad \quad {something 2} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be better if you turned your code snippet into a a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Note that there should be no blank line in an `align` environment. I presume that the ones in the example code were due to copy paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using the `\MoveEqLeft` command from `mathtools` and having only one number for the constraints. If your want independent numbring of constraints, I have a solution with `alignat`:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools, cases}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\label{green}
\MoveEqLeft\text{Minimize: }\notag\\
& \quad {∑_{\tau=t}^{t+T-1}}s(τ)\bigl[Vβ(τ)-Q(τ)-X(τ)-Y(τ)\bigr] +{∑_{\tau=t}^{t+T-1}}\bigl[(X(τ)+Y(τ))(γ b(τ)-γ v(τ))\bigr] \\
 \MoveEqLeft\text{subject to}
\qquad \!\begin{cases}
\hspace*{0.5em} 0 \leq s(τ)\leq s_{\max}, \quad ∀ τ \\
\hspace*{0.5em}\displaystyle∑_{\mathclap{\tau=t}}^{\mathclap{t+T-1}} γ β(τ)\leq N_{\max}
\end{cases}
\end{align}


\begin{alignat}{2}
\label{green}
\MoveEqLeft[2]\text{Minimize: }\notag\\
& ∑_{\tau=t}^{t+T-1}s(τ) & &\bigl[Vβ(τ)-Q(τ)-X(τ)-Y(τ)\bigr] +{∑_{\tau=t}^{t+T-1}}\bigl[(X(τ)+Y(τ))(γ b(τ)-γ v(τ))\bigr] \\[1ex]
 \MoveEqLeft \text{subject to}
 & & 0 \leq s(τ)\leq s_{\max}, \quad ∀ τ \\
& & & \displaystyle∑_{\mathclap{\tau=t}}^{\mathclap{t+T-1}} γ β(τ)\leq N_{\max}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use `split` inside `align`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\text{minimize}\qquad &
  \sum_{\tau=t}^{t+T-1} s(\tau)[V\beta(\tau)-Q(\tau)-X(\tau)-Y(\tau)] \\
  &\qquad  +\sum_{\tau=t}^{t+T-1} [(X(\tau)+Y(\tau))(\gamma b(\tau)-\gamma v(\tau))]
  \end{split}
\label{green} 
\\[2ex]
\text{subject to}\qquad & 0\leq s(\tau)\leq s_{\textup{max}}, \quad \forall \tau   
\label{green-constraint-1} 
\\
& \sum_{\tau=t}^{t+T-1} \gamma \beta(\tau)\leq N_{\textup{max}}
\label{green-constraint-2}
\end{align}

Check: \eqref{green} with \eqref{green-constraint-1} and \eqref{green-constraint-2}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{align}
    \shortintertext{Minimize}   
    \MoveEqLeft[3]\sum\nolimits_{\tau=t}^{t+T-1}s(\tau)[V\beta(\tau)-Q(\tau)-X(\tau)-Y(\tau)] \nonumber \\
    +{}&\sum\nolimits_{\tau=t}^{t+T-1}[(X(\tau)+Y(\tau))(\gamma b(\tau)-\gamma v(\tau))]\label{green}\\
    \shortintertext{subject to} 
    &0\leq s(\tau)\leq s_\text{max}, \quad \forall \tau \\  
    &\sum\nolimits_{\tau=t}^{t+T-1} \gamma \beta(\tau)\leq N_\text{max}
\end{align} 
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @SabbirHasan Glad to hear that.